# Sum columns from two relatable tables and group by another column (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

Given two tables:

- teachers: ID, school_id
- schools:  ID, student_population, district.

...what query can sum the number of teachers and students by district?

sample data:

```
Teachers
ID, school_id
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
4, 3

Schools
ID, student_population, district
1, 45, Falaba
2, 23, Falaba
3, 87, Bonth
4, 10, Moyamba
```

Desired results:

```
teachers, students, district
3, 68, Falaba
1, 87, Bonth
0, 10, Moyamba
```

My first try was:

```
select count(*) as teachers, sum(student_population), district from teachers join schools on teachers.school_id = schools.id group by district.
```

...however, this query results in each school's student_population being factored for each teacher who belongs to it. Consequently, the total student population for Falaba results to 113 (45+45+23) instead of 68.

Comment: What is the primary key of the `teachers` table?

Comment: It's just ID. I thought to leave it out for simplicity.

Comment: It's not a primary key, since it contains duplicated values. This table probably contains another column that stores the id of the teacher associated to the school - if so, you should show that column in your sample data (also see my answer, which assumes so).

Comment: @GMB It is not necessary to know constraints to query. (But when constraints hold, additional queries return the same results as queries that don't assume constraints.)

Comment: "group number of teachers and students by district" is unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. This will be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Please show what parts you can do. Please don't ask for your code to be written for you. Please ask 1 question re the 1st place you are stuck, describing your difficulty. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Also [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS What is the criteria for a row being in or not being in Teachers? Schools? The result?

Comment: Please show working parts & if you give some big thing that doesn't work give working code that it extends.--Please act on all the other comment requests too. Please format code reasonably. PS (Now that you fixed Teachers:) This is a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. (Although sometimes one can simultaneously aggretate via UNIQUE and/or CASE.)

Comment: Thank you, @philipxy, I've tried to update the question accordingly.

Comment: My last comment was after your edit before the title edit you just made; it still applies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SUM and COUNT returning wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545771/sql-sum-and-count-returning-wrong-values)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that table `teachers` has (at least) a second column that contains the id of the teacher, you can do:

```
select
    count(distinct t.teacher_id) teachers
    sum(s.student_population) students,
    s.district
from schools s
inner join teachers t on t.school_id = s.id
group by s.district
```

A better option is to pre-aggregate the `teachers` table:

```
select
    sum(t.teachers) teachers,
    sum(s.student_population) students,
    s.district
from schools s
inner join (select school_id, count(*) teachers from teachers group by school_id) t 
    on t.school_id = s.id
group by s.district
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3197a9a5bd4ee80eac1bf63719a03300)**:

```
teachers | students | district
-------: | -------: | :-------
       1 |       87 | Bonth   
       3 |       68 | Falaba
```

Comment: Results with this query:

teachers, students, district
first row: 1, 87, Bonth.
second row: 3, 113, Falaba.

Since there are more teacher rows than schools, in this case, the first school in Falaba is being counted thrice: 45+45+23.

Comment: @MikeFabrikant: I see. I updated my answer with another (and tested) solution.

Comment: Thank you, this was incredibly helpful. I altered your solution slightly to account for student populations within schools that might not have teachers assigned to them in the teachers table:
select
    sum(COALESCE(t.teachers, 0)) teachers,
    sum(s.student_population) students,
    s.district
from schools s
 left join (select school_id, count(*) teachers from teachers group by school_id) t 
    on t.school_id = s.id
group by s.district;

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c6b565e13f8d5d22f7d8d03c2a20a6d7